# How to refactor for loop method to break when there are no elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I change this method to work with different number of elements? 
Sometimes there can be for example 3 elements, and another time 5.
I would like this loop to look for elements as long as it can find it, and if not, to break. 
Now, when there is only 3 elements, there is an error "unable to locate element" and tests fails.

```
public void checkProductsInOrder() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//td[@data-id=\"product_name\"])[" + i + "]"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        productsInOrder.add(element.getText());
    }
```

Comment: `if(element == null) break;`?

Comment: @Subburaj You don’t need to write a comment to tell us you have written an answer. Everyone interested will find the answer by themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `findElements` method to find all the matched element and then iterate the loop for only the matched element. `findElements` method will find all the matched elements based on the locator.

Please check the modified code

```
//It will match all the product name based on the xpath (index alone needs to be removed from your index)
      List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//td[@data-id='product_name'])"));

        int size=element.size();

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            productsInOrder.add(element.get(i).getText()); 
        }
```

Comment: Still easier: `for (WebElement elem : element) { productsInOrder.add(elem.getText()); }`. It’s called the *enhanced for loop* in case you want to look it up.

Comment: yeah. we can use foreach loop as well. For the understanding purpose, I have given with for loop. Thanks Ole for sharing the info!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to Selenium (in which case, [it seems there's a better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527720/1898563)), but sometimes APIs don't give you multiple options so it's worthwhile to know:

It's a common pattern when reading lines from a file in Java. Declare a variable before a while-loop and both assign and compare it within the condition. I'd also refactor the `findElement` to its own method to increase readability.

```
private WebElement findElement(final int num)
{
    return driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("(//td[@data-id=\"product_name\"])[" + num + "]")
    );
}
```

Your method would look like:

```
WebElement element;
int count = 0;
while ((element = findElement(count++)) != null)
{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    productsInOrder.add(element.getText());
}
```